# Oracle check constraint for varray type

Tags: oracle, constraints

I have a custom type defined as this :

```
CREATE TYPE myType_t AS VARRAY(2) of char(10);
```

Is it possible to add a check constraint on the char(10) type, so myType_t items respect a certain regex? I tried things like

```
CREATE TYPE myType_t AS VARRAY(2) of char(10)
( constraint c_myType_format check ( regexp_like(IdontKnowWhatToWriteHere, '[:digit:]{8}'));
```

which obviously doesn't work... I thought maybe defining another type for the

```
AS VARRAY(2) of myOtherType_t
```

but here again I don't know where to put the regex check.

And yes, I also tried adding the constraint to the table that will use my type, but I can't find the correct syntax.

Comment: Why not change `char(10)` to `number(8)`? Admittedly, won't stop negative numbers, though...

Comment: Well, I thought it wouldn't have the same meaning to store it as a number, although I know it would have been possible.

Comment: Fair enough - I agree if it's not actually a number, but a string of digits, it's best to not use the number data type. In this case I'd shy away from TYPEs and just put constraints on the database columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to Oracle documentation:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#i1002038)

> Oracle does not support constraints on columns or attributes whose
>   type is a user-defined object, nested table, VARRAY, REF, or LOB